# How to reference an Obj by a key inside of it in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say I have an array of objects:

```
inventory = [{name:'milk',price:4},{name:'apple',price:2}]
```

How could I reference the entire object that contains inventory.name = 'milk' or inventory.price = 4?

I need to reference it in order to return its index inside of the outer array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways, but the first is:

```
const obj = inventory.find(object => object.name === "milk" || object.price === 4)
```

or you can use findIndex

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
const index = inventory.findIndex(item => item.name === 'milk');
```

Or use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you want the actual object.